# How to highlight a word in an image?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'd like to be able to highlight a word in an image of a document when the user searches for that word.  Exactly like Google Books does 
[here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ykcLAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=okubo&f=false).

As far as I know, Tesseract and other open source OCR programs don't support this sort of function, so does anyone have any ideas how it might be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they "support" it. Sort of.

They give you a rectangle that tells you where the word is. Using that, fill said rectangle with the color of your choice on the image using a [color blending mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Color) (e.g., keep the luma intact and just alter the chroma). This works well with B/W and grayscale images, which most books are, and is sufficient for most colored fonts too (except those in a colored background). A solution to this is to invert the colors instead of highlighting them, this is done in many applications (Foxit Reader comes to mind).

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I don't know Tesseract well enough.  I just thought it outputted a text file.  Where do I find these rectangles?

Comment: See here: http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/ it's an  open-source C# wrapper.

Comment: i want to highlight text when clicked image then recognize i am using google vision library what to do?